# Get Jetty HttpClient to follow redirects

Tags: jetty, jetty-8

I've got a program that uses Jetty version 8 to send an http post.  My response handler works, but I'm getting an http response code 303, which is a redirect.  I read a comment that jetty 8 has support for following these redirects, but I can not figure out how to set it up.  I've tried looking at the [javadocs](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/package-summary.html), and I found the RedirectListener class, but no details on how to use it.  My attempts at guessing how to code it haven't worked so I'm stuck.  All help is appreciated!

**Edit**

I looked through the jetty source code and found that it will only redirect when the response code is either 301 or 302.  I was able to override the RedirectListener to get it to handle repose code 303 as well.  After that Joakim's code works perfectly.

```
public class MyRedirectListener extends RedirectListener
{
   public MyRedirectListener(HttpDestination destination, HttpExchange ex)
   {
      super(destination, ex);
   }

   @Override
   public void onResponseStatus(Buffer version, int status, Buffer reason)
       throws IOException
   {
      // Since the default RedirectListener only cares about http
      // response codes 301 and 302, we override this method and
      // trick the super class into handling this case for us.
      if (status == HttpStatus.SEE_OTHER_303)
         status = HttpStatus.MOVED_TEMPORARILY_302;

      super.onResponseStatus(version,status,reason);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough

```java
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.registerListener(RedirectListener.class.getName());
client.start();

// do your exchange here
ContentExchange get = new ContentExchange();
get.setMethod(HttpMethods.GET);
get.setURL(requestURL);

client.send(get);
int state = get.waitForDone();
int status = get.getResponseStatus();
if(status != HttpStatus.OK_200)
   throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get content: " + status);
String content = get.getResponseContent();

// do something with the content

client.stop();
```

Comment: I've been trying to get this working.  Do I need to implement my own RedirectListener? When use the default implementation my onResponseComplete handler still gets called with a 303, but I never get the final response.

Comment: Try adjusting the HttpClient.setMaxRedirects(int) to a higher number.  It could also be that the redirect you are seeing isn't conforming to the 303 + `Location:` response header standard (like some url shorteners do)

Comment: Thank you Joakim! I found out what was keeping my code from working.  Once I fixed that your example worked great.